# What does ampersand "&" do in front of pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, operators

When functions are being called I often see the ampersand in front of the pointer in the function parameter.

E.g.

```
int *ptr;
randomFunction(&ptr);
```

I have done some research and found that this means that the function uses pointers to pointers. Is the `&` sign in front of a pointer used just to indicate this or does it do something else?

Comment: returns the address of it. So `&ptr` will return an `int**` You would usually do this if you want the function to change what the pointer points at or do some sort of assignment to it.

Comment: Address of ptr. ie int** here

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: That's rather obsolete (C style). In C++, you'd use `int*&` for that.

Comment: @MSalters We have different opinions on obsolete I guess. Sometimes you want the user to be able to enter "nullptr". You cannot do this with a reference. Also it makes it "more" obvious what is being done to the parameter passed. Other than that, you are indeed very right. I myself tend to use `T* &ptr` more than `T**`. But you know, sometimes there's always that exception mentioned above.

Comment: @Brandon but you can change what pointer points to without getting pointer to the pointer and you can lead assignment too.

Answer (score 41):

### It's a pointer to the pointer.

`&` is the reference operator, and can be read as `address of`. In your example, it will get another pointer, that is the address of the pointer given as it's argument, i.e. a pointer to the pointer.

Look at the following example:

```
int **ipp;
int i = 5, j = 6, k = 7;
int *ip1 = &i, *ip2 = &j;
ipp = &ip1;
```

You will get:

[image]

In the above example, `ipp` is a pointer to pointer. `ipp` stores the address of `ip1` and `ip1` stores the address of `i`.

You can check out [Pointers to Pointers](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html) for more info.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but why would one want to use a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @JDMDev One example would be COM uses ptr-to-ptr to return an interface pointer using `CoCreateInstance()` and `IUnknown::QueryInterface()`. Check out [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer) for more info.

Answer (score 9):

Take a step back. The fundamental rules of pointer operators are:

- The `*` operator turns a *value* of type `pointer to T` into a *variable* of type `T`.
- The `&` operator turns a *variable* of type `T` into a *value* of type `pointer to T`.

So when you have

```
int *ptr;
```

`ptr` is a variable of type `pointer to int`. Therefore `*ptr` is a variable of type `int` -- the `*` turns a *pointer* into a *variable*.  You can say `*ptr = 123;`.

Since `ptr` is a variable of type `pointer to int`, `&ptr` is a *value* -- not a variable -- of type `pointer to pointer to int`:

```
int **pp = &ptr;
```

`&ptr` is a value of type `pointer to pointer to int`. `pp` is a variable of type `pointer to pointer to int`.  `*pp` is a variable of type `pointer to int`, and in fact is the *same* variable as `ptr`. The `*` is the *inverse* of the `&`.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think of "&" this way. 
    int function_name (  &( whatever )   );
You are passing the address of ( whatever ).
Whatever can be a number of things:
an elementary variable.
a function.
a structure.
a union. 
an array.
You should mentally translate "&" to
 "take the address of". So your example means : 
pass a COPY of the address 
of the address of the variable ptr of type int!

Comment: Do you mean '&' should be '*'

Comment: @DamienJoe: No! `&` is the opposit of `*`. `&` takes the address of it's argument and `*` returns what`s stored under it's argument (interpreting the argument as address).

Comment: @alk Thanks for the info. Updated my concepts with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Int *ptr;
```

&ptr returns the address of a pointer variable ptr. In short, double pointer or int** holds the address of ptr with &ptr.